# jquery increment input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Jquery I need to add all values of input.

Using jquery each is there any way to use regix in element name
like 
items[regix_goes_here][debit]

I need values of all input and I want them incremented using each.

My code

```
<input name="items[1][debit]" type="number">
<input name="items[341][debit]" type="number">
<input name="items[31][debit]" type="number">
<input name="items[431][debit]" type="number">
```

Comment: What is `regix`? It's really not clear what you're asking, nor what the goal is.

Comment: Do you want it `regix_goes_here` number to increase for each input?

Comment: Another thing, its bad practice to have multiple elements on the same page with the same id, Use class for that

Comment: I need to get all input elements values of above code.Thats all I need using jquery each

Comment: why do you need to do it using regex?

Comment: How do you want to get those values, by a submit event or click event or? Please clarify your question

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen name="items[431][debit]"   numbers are random inside name that's why or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You can do it of course multiple ways. But regular **ix**pression is not the most convenient.

Comment: @Peter didn't you said you want `Regex` to do it? Take a look at my answer, isn't that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, assign a class to your inputs, for example:

```
<input class="js-inc" name="items[1][debit]" type="number">
<input class="js-inc" name="items[341][debit]" type="number">
<input class="js-inc" name="items[31][debit]" type="number">
<input class="js-inc" name="items[431][debit]" type="number">
```

Now you can increment all of them, without even jquery. Use `.value` to access the value as a string. Use `Number("..")` to convert it to a number. Add one to it, and assign it back.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.js-inc")
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    input.value = Number(input.value) + 1
})
```

Here's a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/2eycam8m/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all the values of inputs with `name="items[X][Y]"`, you can filter them by testing if their `name` attribute matches this `/items\[\d+\]\[debit\]/` **[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/0Av711/1)**.

This is how should be your code:

```
var sum = 0;
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') && $(this).attr('name').match(/items\[\d+\]\[debit\]/)) {
      sum += $(this).val() ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
    }
  });
  console.log(sum);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var sum = 0;
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') && $(this).attr('name').match(/items\[\d+\]\[debit\]/)) {
      sum += $(this).val() ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
    }
  });
  console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="items[1][debit]" type="number" value="2">
<input name="items[341][debit]" type="number" value="2">
<input name="items[31][debit]" type="number" value="2">
<input name="items[431][debit]" type="number" value="2">
<input type="button" value="SUM" />
```